# Algorithm to Recursively Process Self-Referencing Entity

Tags: c#-4.0, recursion, entity-framework-4.3

I have the following entity definitions:

```cs
public class Member
{
  [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required] public string Name { get; set; }

  [Required] public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; } // Must be a member of at least one group
}

public class Group
{
  [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required] public string Name { get; set; }

  public int? ParentGroupId { get; set; }
  public Group ParentGroup { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; } // Must contain at least one member (unless it contains subgroups - see below)
}
```

And the Fluent mapping configuration:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Many-to-Many Group <--> Member
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
      .HasMany(g => g.Members)
      .WithMany(m => m.Groups)
      .Map(map =>
            {
              map.ToTable("GroupMembers");
              map.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
              map.MapRightKey("MemberId");
            });

    // Self-referencing Group to allow for hierarchy of groups
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
      .HasOptional(g => g.ParentGroup)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(pg => pg.ParentGroupId);
}
```

The validation rules are as follows:

- A `Member` *must* belong to at least one `Group`
- A `Group` *must* contain `Members`; if a `Group` has no members, then it *must* be a parent group containing subgroups, all of which *must* contain at least one member. In effect, the members of the subgroups should be inherited by the parent group (but only conceptually, the parent group should still be bereft of actual members)
- A non-parent `Group` *must* contain at least one member

So, how do I validate this? I need to find all groups without members, check if each one "contains" subgroups, then perform the same check recursively on each of the subgroups until I end up with non-parent groups - it is at this point that I check if each group contains members.

I have no idea how to do this elegantly. Instead of spending hours staring at code that probably isn't correct, going around in circles writing and refactoring into oblivion, and banging my head against the wall every few minutes, I've decided to enlist the help of the thinktank that is StackOverflow. :)

Is recursion the way to go, or is there a better alternative? Thanks in advance.